# How can symbols in photographies be identified programatically?

Tags: image-processing

I have a background in web development and I am researching a project that needs to be able to identify symbols (similar to brands on clothes or bags) in photographies.
Where should I start looking?

Answer (score 0):

if it is for web purposes you can convert your necessary images to fonts and identify each one with their unique code,.,.

or use the existing set of
for example you can use [bootstrap glyphicons](http://marcoceppi.github.io/bootstrap-glyphicons/)

main source of [glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/)

[allways photography](http://www.allwaysphotography.nl) used glyphicons